# Java - Threads resources and executing time

Tags: java

To get the execution time of a Thread, I'm using

```
ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getThreadCpuTime(t1.getId())
```

where t1 is a thread.

Now I need to print the resources a thread is using, is there any way to know the resources?

Comment: What do you mean by resources?

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce a `printResources` method in your threaded class and then cast `t1` to its native class in which you can call the `printResources` method.